# How to use .classList.add("hide"); to hide curtains when viewing a 2nd time

Tags: javascript, html, hide, hidden

Curtains stay hidden when `.setAttribute("hidden", true);` is being used. https://jsfiddle.net/g2th3opc/

```
evt.currentTarget.closest(".inner-container").querySelector(".sliding-panels").setAttribute("hidden", true);
```

Curtains **don't** stay hidden when `.classList.add("hide");` is being used. https://jsfiddle.net/06vdjka4/

```
evt.currentTarget.closest(".inner-container").querySelector(".sliding-panels").classList.add("hide");
```

**To reproduce:** Click 1 svg play button, then click the **X**.

Do that repeatedly, click on all of them, even the ones you already clicked on.

You will notice that the curtains don't stay hidden when `.classList.add("hide");` is being used.

The curtains are supposed to stay hidden after clicking on the same svg play button a 2nd time.

Why don't they stay hidden, and is there a fix for that?

I tried to **post a snippet** but it went over the character limit.

Comment: It would be better if you included your code as a runnable snippet instead of linking to JSFiddle.

Comment: I tried to post a snippet but it went over the character limit.

Comment: In those cases it is best to try and trim down your code to something closer to a **minimal** reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Doing so will make life a lot easier for those trying to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the way you are showing the buttons:

```js
  function showAllButtons(buttonSelector) {
    const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

    function showButton(button) {
      // This is where the hide class is getting removed
      button.classList.remove("hide");
    }
    allButtons.forEach(showButton);
  }

  function resetPage() {
    resetBackground("body");
    resetCurtains(".with-curtain");

    // You aren't just matching buttons with this selector. You are matching everything that has been hidden!
    showAllButtons(".hide");

    resetButtons(".outer");
  }

  // This is called whenever an exit button is clicked
  function exitClickHandler(evt) {
    resetPage(); // During this function calls all other .sliding-panels divs are show
    // This only hides the current video's .sliding-panels div
    evt.currentTarget.closest(".inner-container").querySelector(".sliding-panels").classList.add("hide");
  }
```

The solution is to be more specific with your selector for un-hiding buttons:

```
    // Notice the increased specificity of this selector:
    showAllButtons(".container.hide");
```

```js
const manageUI = (function makeManageUI() {

  function resetBackground(backgroundSelector) {
    const allBackgrounds = document.querySelectorAll(backgroundSelector);

    function showBackground(background) {
      background.classList.remove("bg1");
    }
    allBackgrounds.forEach(showBackground);
  }

  function resetCurtains(curtainSelector) {
    const allCurtains = document.querySelectorAll(curtainSelector);

    function showCurtain(curtain) {
      curtain.classList.remove("active");
    }
    allCurtains.forEach(showCurtain);
  }

  function showAllButtons(buttonSelector) {
    const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

    function showButton(button) {
      button.classList.remove("hide");
    }
    allButtons.forEach(showButton);
  }

  function resetButtons(buttonSelector) {
    const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

    function showButton(button) {
      button.classList.remove("isOpen");
    }
    allButtons.forEach(showButton);
  }

  function resetPage() {
    resetBackground("body");
    resetCurtains(".with-curtain");
    // Notice the increased specificity of this selector:
    showAllButtons(".container.hide");
    resetButtons(".outer");
  }

  function exitClickHandler(evt) {
    resetPage();
    evt.currentTarget.closest(".inner-container").querySelector(".sliding-panels").classList.add("hide");
  }

  function addClickToExit(exitButtons) {
    exitButtons.forEach(function addExitButtonHandler(exitButtons) {
      exitButtons.addEventListener("click", exitClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function init() {
    const exitButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    addClickToExit(exitButtons);
  }

  return {
    init
  };
}());

const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {
  const config = {};

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function hide(el) {
    el.classList.add("hide");
  }

  function hideAll(elements) {
    elements.forEach(hide);
  }

  function resetBackground(backgroundSelector) {
    const allBackgrounds = document.querySelectorAll(backgroundSelector);

    function hideBackground(background) {
      background.classList.add("bg1");
    }
    allBackgrounds.forEach(hideBackground);
  }

  function resetButtons(buttonSelector) {
    const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector);

    function hideButton(button) {
      button.classList.add("isOpen");
    }
    allButtons.forEach(hideButton);
  }

  function resetPage() {
    resetBackground("body");
    resetButtons(".outer");
  }

  function markAsPlayed(played) {
    played.classList.add("played");
  }

  function showCovers(playButton) {
    const cover = playButton.parentElement;
    cover.classList.add("active");
    show(cover);
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    hideAll(config.containers);
    resetPage();
    markAsPlayed(evt.currentTarget);
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    showCovers(cover);
  }

  function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
    playButtons.forEach(function playButtonHandler(playButton) {
      playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
  }

  function init(selectors) {
    config.containers = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.container);
    const playButtons = document.querySelectorAll(selectors.playButton);
    addClickToButtons(playButtons);
  }

  return {
    addCoverHandler,
    init
  };
}());

function combinePlayerOptions(options1 = {}, options2 = {}) {
  const combined = Object.assign({}, options1, options2);
  Object.keys(options1).forEach(function checkObjects(prop) {
    if (typeof options1[prop] === "object") {
      combined[prop] = Object.assign({}, options1[prop], options2[prop]);
    }
  });
  return combined;
}

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {
  const players = [];

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function createStopHandler(player) {
    const stopButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    stopButtons.forEach(function stopButtonHandler(button) {
      button.addEventListener("click", function buttonClickHandler() {
        player.stopVideo();
      });
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
    createStopHandler(player);
  }

  function addPlayer(video, settings) {
    const defaults = {
      height: 360,
      host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
      videoId: video.dataset.id,
      width: 640
    };
    defaults.events = {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady
    };

    const playerOptions = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, settings);
    const player = new YT.Player(video, playerOptions);
    players.push(player);
    return player;
  }

  return {
    addPlayer
  };
}());

const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {
  const defaults = {
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 0,
      controls: 1,
      disablekb: 1,
      enablejsapi: 1,
      fs: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3
    }
  };

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function createPlayer(videoWrapper, settings = {}) {
    const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
    const playerOptions = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, settings);
    return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, playerOptions);
  }

  function createCoverClickHandler(playerOptions) {
    return function coverClickHandler(evt) {
      const cover = evt.currentTarget;
      const wrapper = cover.nextElementSibling;
      show(wrapper);
      const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
      wrapper.player = player;
    };
  }

  function addPlayer(coverSelector, playerOptions) {
    const clickHandler = createCoverClickHandler(playerOptions);
    manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, clickHandler);
  }

  return {
    add: addPlayer
  };

}());

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {

  managePlayer.add(".playa", {});
  managePlayer.add(".playb", {});
  managePlayer.add(".playc", {});
  managePlayer.add(".playd", {});
  managePlayer.add(".playe", {
    playerVars: {
      playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
    }
  });
  managePlayer.add(".playe", {});
  managePlayer.add(".playf", {});
  managePlayer.add(".playg", {});
  managePlayer.add(".playh", {});
  managePlayer.add(".playi", {});

  manageCover.init({
    container: ".container",
    playButton: ".thePlay"
  });

  manageUI.init({});

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #353198;
  animation: fade 2s ease 0s forwards;
}


@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 290px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  gap: 10px;
}

.outer.isOpen {
  display: flex;
  width: auto;
  align-content: stretch;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  /*z-index: 2;*/
}


.container.active {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

body.bg1 {
  animation: fadebody 5s ease 0s forwards;
}

.thePlay:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(43, 179, 20, 0.5);
}

.thePlay:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.inner-container {
  display: none;
}

/* when container is active hide the svg and show the inner container*/
.container.active .thePlay {
  display: none;
}

.container.active .inner-container {
  display: flex;
}

.container.active .inner-container.curtain {
  display: block;
}

@keyframes fadebody {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.thePlay {
  
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  fill: blue;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}

.played {
   fill: green;
}



button.thePlay {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47.63px;
  height: 47.63px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  fill: red;
  padding: 0;
}

.exitsvg {
  fill: none;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
  stroke: #ff0000;
  stroke-width: 17.80202103;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  stroke-dasharray: none;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  border: 4.625px solid #4e4e4e;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.curtain {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 642px;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  background: #0a0a0a;
  border: 20px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
}

.panel-left,
.panel-right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  /* rounding error fix */
  top: 0%;
  transition: all ease 10s;

  /*background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/600");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;*/
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel-left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(91, 96, 106);*/
}

.panel-right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: rgb(229, 211, 211);*/
}

.panel-left::before,
.panel-right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'> <filter id='filter'> <feTurbulence baseFrequency='0.01 0.0001' numOctaves='5'/> <feColorMatrix values='1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1'/></filter> <rect width='100%' height='100%' filter='url(%23filter)'/> </svg>");
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.panel-right::before {
  left: -100%;
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-left {
  animation: curtain1 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain1 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain2 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain2 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain3 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain3 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}
.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain4 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain4 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}


.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain5 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain5 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain6 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain6 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain7 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain7 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain8 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain8 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}

.container.active .curtain .panel-right {
  animation: curtain9 8s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes curtain9 {
  to {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
}


.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;

  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.video-frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container with-curtain">
    <button class="playa thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <g id="play">
          <title>Play</title>
          <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" fill="transparent" pointer-events="visiblePainted" />
          <path d="M25.6,46.4L44.8,32L25.6,17.6V46.4z M32,0C14.3,0,0,14.3,0,32s14.3,32,32,32s32-14.3,32-32S49.7,0,32,0z
                  M32,57.6C17.9,57.6,6.4,46.1,6.4,32S17.9,6.4,32,6.4S57.6,17.9,57.6,32S46.1,57.6,32,57.6z" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain1">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="CHahce95B1g"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <g id="exit">
            <title>exit</title>
            <path d="M 6.3895625,6.4195626 C 93.580437,93.610437 93.580437,93.610437 93.580437,93.610437" />
            <path d="M 6.3894001,93.6106 C 93.830213,6.4194003 93.830213,6.4194003 93.830213,6.4194003" />
          </g>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play2 with-curtain">
    <button class="playb thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain2">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play3 with-curtain">
    <button class="playc thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain3">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play4 with-curtain">
    <button class="playd thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain4">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play5 with-curtain">
    <button class="playe thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain5">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play6 with-curtain">
    <button class="playf thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain6">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play7 with-curtain">
    <button class="playg thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain7">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play8 with-curtain">
    <button class="playh thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain8">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container play9 with-curtain">
    <button class="playi thePlay" type="button" aria-label="Open">
      <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <use href="#play" />
      </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="inner-container curtain curtain9">
      <div class="ratio-keeper">
        <div class="wrapa">
          <div class="video video-frame" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="sliding-panels">
          <div class="panel-left"></div>
          <div class="panel-right"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="exit" type="button" aria-label="Close">
        <svg class="exitsvg" width="38.39" height="38.39" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
          <use href="#exit" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should I change the name of showAllButtons to something else, and if so, what would be a good name for it?

Comment: `showAllElementsMatchingSelector`

Answer (score 0):

Just do this small fix to exit handler.

```
function exitClickHandler(evt) {
resetPage();

evt.currentTarget
    .closest(".inner-container")
    .querySelector(".sliding-panels")
    .removeAttribute("hidden"); //remove hidden attribute on exit
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h9yfd1nv/